# Test if an an array of pointers has some value in it

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, strtok

I basically want to test if  `char *tk[2];`  has some value or not stored .

My programs has to do something when tk[0] and tk[1] both have values(a char stored in each of them) , but also do something else when only tk[0] is initialized with something and tk[1] is "empty".

This is my function where i initialize my array of pointers , that uses strtok.
The keywords can be something like "key1 key2" or "key1",so maximum 2 words.

```
void key(char *keywords[], char *tk[], int k) {
    int p = 0;
    char *delim = " \n";
    int length = strlen(keywords[k]);
    char buffer_key[length];
    strcpy(buffer_key, keywords[k]);
    char *token_key = strtok(buffer_key, delim);
    while (token_key != NULL) {
        tk[p++] = token_key;
        token_key = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}
```

and this is the block of code from my main function where i call the **key** function .

```
    char *tk[2];
     key(keywords, tk, k);
```

Next i want to check if only tk[0] has a char stored (so tk[1] is empty?).
How can i check this ?

Comment: Huge assumption here that `p++` will never exceed the size of `tk`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C , and also new to programming. Bare with me.

Comment: Understand that and I'm just pointing out a potential pitfall as C will not do this for you. It will just invoke undefined behaviour and leave you wondering why your program crashes or has scrambled values.

Comment: if my list of given keywords **must** have only one or two words , how can it still happen? and if it does , how i fix it this issue?

Comment: `int length = strlen(keywords[k]); char buffer_key[length];  strcpy(buffer_key, keywords[k]);`  is _undefined behavior_ **UB** as `strpcy()` writes outside the array,

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `tk` before calling the function. Then you can test if the values are filled in after it returns.

```
char *tk[2] = {0};
key(keywords, tk, k);
if (tk[0] && !tk[1]) {
    // do something
}
```